# making a button that turns on/off background music in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, audio

A brief description : I want to make `<h1>` as a button to turn on/off background music. By far I have succeed in turning `<h1>` as a clickable button that either plays or pauses music (using `.play()` : js code down below)  but no luck combining those two functions.

I figured I could use `.onclick` and `conditional statements` in order to make it work but I want to know if I could perhaps use `toggleAttribute()` since It removes given element if exists and adds if doesn't exist. (as pause if clicked and resume if re-clicked)

I will leave my code for a better understanding of the contents. 
HTML:

```html
<div class="musicOn">
    <audio id="audio" style="display:none;" src="christmas.mp3" controls autoplay loop onloadeddata="setHalfVolume()">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Tic <span>Tac</span> Toe</h1>
```

JavaScript:

```js
let on_off = document.querySelector('.container .title');

on_off.onclick = function() {
  audio.play()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two solutions (two snippets).

In the first solution, the button works like a toggle on the `pause / play` principle. In the second solution, the toggle works like a `stop / play`.

1. pause / play:

```js
let on_off = document.querySelector('.container .title');
let audio = document.querySelector('.musicOn audio');

on_off.onclick = function() {
  audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
}
```

```html
<div class="musicOn">
    <audio id="audio" style="display:none;" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/jingle/jingle_02.mp3" controls autoplay loop>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Tic <span>Tac</span> Toe</h1>
  </div>
```

2. stop / play

```js
let on_off = document.querySelector('.container .title');
let audio = document.querySelector('.musicOn audio');

on_off.onclick = function() {
  audio.paused ? audio.play() : music_stop();
}

function music_stop() {
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="musicOn">
    <audio id="audio" style="display:none;" src="http://www.sousound.com/music/jingle/jingle_02.mp3" controls autoplay loop>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Tic <span>Tac</span> Toe</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can check whether an audio is paused or not, using audio.paused, paused is read only.

You can however use audio.paused in your click function to test whether you need to play or pause the audio.

```js
let on_off = document.querySelector('.container .title');
let audio = document.getElementById('audio');
on_off.onclick = function() {
  if (audio.paused) { audio.play(); }
  else { audio.pause(); }
}
```

```html
<div class="musicOn">
    <audio id="audio" style="display:none;" src="https://ahweb.org.uk/blackbird.mp3" controls loop></audio>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">Tic <span>Tac</span> Toe</h1>
    </div>
```